# how to delete media library in save picture photo in windows phone c#

Tags: windows-phone-8

when delete image from media library, i'am getting access denied error.
this is my code.

```
using (MediaLibrary _MediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())
{
    foreach (PictureAlbum album in _MediaLibrary.RootPictureAlbum.Albums)
    {
        if (album.Name == "Saved Pictures")
        {
            PictureCollection Pictures = album.Pictures;
            foreach (Picture _Picture in Pictures)
            {
                if (_Picture.Name.Contains("Tattoo_" + FavoritesName))
                {
                    File.Delete(_Picture.GetPath());
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to delete pictures from the media library. Some kind of security constrain, I guess.